# Adding Field to Profile "Name"

Tags: php, admin, profiles

I am trying to add an extra field or two underneath the "Name" or "About" section in the Wordpress user profile. So far I have only been able to accomplish this by:

```
//Begin
add_action('profile_personal_options',function(){
    ob_start();
});

//Grab Contents and Inject
add_action('show_user_profile',function($user){
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo str_replace('<label for="description','!!!!!<label for="description',$contents);
});
```

But this seems like a dirty hack - what is the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: read: http://wpengineer.com/2173/custom-fields-wordpress-user-profile/  And adjust the author-bio template to call in your custom user meta.

Comment: I believe that just adds it to the bottom of the page, I was hoping to add it either to the name or about category

Comment: Use this filter return apply_filters( 'get_the_author_' . $field, $value, $user_id );

Answer (score 0):

check out my older article

**HOW TO ADD WORDPRESS AUTHOR BIO & PROFILE PAGE**

https://phirebase.com/blog/how-to-add-author-bio-profile-page/

just short example to add Twitter and Facebook fields:

```
function my_new_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
// Add Twitter
$contactmethods['twitter'] = 'Twitter';
//Add Facebook
$contactmethods['facebook'] = 'Facebook';
return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_new_contactmethods',10,1);
```

**Single loop**

`<?php the_author_meta('facebook'); ?>`

– show facebook name

`<?php the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>`

– show twitter name

**Author page**

`<?php echo $curauth->facebook; ?>`

– show facebook name

`<?php echo $curauth->twitter; ?>`

– show twitter name

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP specifically asks if there's a way to add a field under the Name or About section. This will add fields to the Contact Info section.